# Can I contribute to community goals while playing solo?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I want to participate on CG but I want to avoid PVP or queues to dock on stations. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**. Players in solo have just as much of an impact on community goals, power play, and the background sim as players in open.